# I can't update all the data in MySQL database with PHP program

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out why the code below only updates the folowing data when i hit the Update Record(s) button:

Language
Phone
Hotel
Type
Amount

Also all the form fields has values inside (previously saved on the database) but when i hit the Update Record(s) button (let's assume i didn't change anything this time) all the records deleted from the database and only the above mentioned records still remain intact.

Can someone please help me to figure out what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include 'auth.php';
require 'connect_db.php';
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$query = "SELECT * from csvdata where id ='".$id."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Update Record(s)</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
{
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$clientDepartment = $_REQUEST['clientDepartment'];
$language = $_REQUEST['language'];
$arrivalDate = $_REQUEST['arrivalDate'];
$passengerName = $_REQUEST['passengerName'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$ticketorHotel = $_REQUEST['ticketorHotel'];
$lastSegFlightNr = $_REQUEST['lastSegFlightNr'];
$arrivalTime = $_REQUEST['arrivalTime'];
$hotel = $_REQUEST['hotel'];
$regNr = $_REQUEST['regNr'];
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$amount = $_REQUEST['amount'];
$update = "update csvdata set clientDepartment='".$clientDepartment."', language='".$language."', arrivalDate='".$arrivalDate."', passengerName='".$passengerName."', phone='".$phone."', ticketorHotel='".$ticketorHotel."', lastSegFlightNr='".$lastSegFlightNr."', arrivalTime='".$arrivalTime."', hotel='".$hotel."', regNr='".$regNr."', type='".$type."', amount='".$amount."' where id='".$id."'" or die(mysqli_error($connection));
mysqli_query($connection, $update) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
$status = "<div style='text-align:center'><h3 class='form-signin-heading'>Record(s) Updated Successfully!</h3></br></br>
<a class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' href='dashboard.php'><i class='fas fa-clipboard-list'></i> Dashboard</a></div>";
echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</div>';
echo "</div>";
}else {
?>
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Update Record(s)</h2>
<input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
<label for="inputClient" class="">Client Department</label>
        <input type="text" name="client" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Client Department" value="<?php echo $row['department'];?>">
<label for="inputLanguage" class="">Language</label>
        <input type="text" name="language" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Language" value="<?php echo $row['language'];?>">    
<label for="inputDate" class="">Arrival Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder=" Enter Arrival Date" value="<?php echo $row['arrivalDate'];?>">    
<label for="inputName" class="">Passenger Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Passenger Name" value="<?php echo $row['passengerName'];?>">
<label for="inputPhone" class="">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone" value="<?php echo $row['phone'];?>">             
<label for="inputTicketor" class="">Ticketor/Hotel</label>
        <input type="text" name="ticketor" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Ticketor/Hotel" value="<?php echo $row['ticketorHotel'];?>">
<label for="inputFlight" class="">LastSeg/FlightNr</label>
        <input type="text" name="flight" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter LastSeg FlighrNr" value="<?php echo $row['lastSegFlightNr'];?>">
<label for="inputTime" class="">Arrival Time</label>
        <input type="text" name="time" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Arrival Time" value="<?php echo $row['arrivalTime'];?>"> 
<label for="inputHotel" class="">Hotel</label>
        <input type="text" name="hotel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Hotel" value="<?php echo $row['hotel'];?>">         
<label for="inputReg" class="">RegNr</label>
        <input type="text" name="reg" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter RegNr" value="<?php echo $row['regNr'];?>">       
<label for="inputType" class="">Type</label>
        <input type="text" name="type" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Type" value="<?php echo $row['type'];?>">        
<label for="inputAmount" class="">Amount</label>
        <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Amount" value="<?php echo $row['amount'];?>">
<p>&nbsp;</p>           
<p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" style="font-size: 1.1rem;" name="submit" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Update Record(s)</button> <a style="font-size: 1.1rem;" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" href="dashboard.php" role="button"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel</a></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Quite hard to understand what your actual problem is, not least because it seems like you might be confusing records (rows) and columns in your description …? Please fix at least that first of all. And then, what have you done so far to debug this? Have you made debug outputs to verify your variables contain what you think they do, etc. …?

Comment: Print out the Statement. and look if it is as expected

Comment: I can update only the columns Language, Phone, Hotel, Type and Amount. Why?@CBroe

Answer (score 0):

Check the input names.

For example RegNr:  Your form contains name="reg" and you are getting the value with $_REQUEST['regNr'] instead of $_REQUEST['reg'];
Same problems with other fields.

Check this link to learn more about the basics FORM/ GET / POST
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: I'm feel a little stupid. It was in front of my eyes!!! My problem is sorted out with your precious help. Thank you very much.